# Error saying php JSON_encode not supported

Tags: php, android, json

Encountered an error, saying `json_encode not supported by web server`.

This is the code:

```
<?php

require_once('db_login.php');
$con=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password);
if(!$con)
    die("Could not connect to database");
else echo "Connected to the server" ;
if(mysql_select_db($db_database,$con))
echo"Connected to database";
else
{echo "Unable to select database",mysql_error();}


$user=$_POST['login1'];
$passwd=$_POST['login2'];

//$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO temp (user,password)VALUES('user','$passwd')");

$sql=mysql_query("select * from appusers where username='$user'");


if (!$sql) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

else
{
echo("Successful");
print(json_encode($sql));
}
?>
```

The code is being used to pass a username and password to an android app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP version 5.2.0 JSON support is part of PHP Core. If you have that version or later, then your PHP was compiled with `--disable-json`. Recompile without it.

If you have a version before 5.2.0 you need to install the PECL JSON library.